# Is this the correct method in using bootstrapping to determine a lower confidence bound?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, sampling

Quite often in industry, due to cost and schedule constraints, decisions must be made on small sample size data. I have 4 cycles-to-failure values resulting from running samples to failure in a fatigue test; 947, 1183, 1063 and 583. It is not possible to obtain any more samples to test.

From this data I believe I can say :
I am 95% confident that the probability of any given part in the population surviving to 500 cycles is 0.82 or greater.

My code is below. Is my approach the correct way to accomplish this using Mathematica ?

Can someone verify these results using another tool ?
Many Thanks.

```
cycles={947,1183,1063,583};
plot1=BarChart[cycles,Frame->True,ChartLabels->{"Sample 1","Sample 2","Sample 3","Sample 4"},LabelingFunction->Above,FrameLabel->{None, "Cycles to Failure",None,None},PlotRange->1750,PlotLabel->"Plot 1"]
```

[image]

```
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, 
SmoothKernelDistribution[cycles]]  (* Nominal Distribution *);
pdf[x_] := PDF[dist, x];
ps[x_] := SurvivalFunction[dist, x];
plot2 = Plot[pdf[x], {x, 0, 2000}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Cycles to Failure", "PDF", None, None}, 
PlotLabel -> "Plot 2\nNominal PDF", PlotStyle -> Red]
plot2a = Plot[ps[x], {x, 0, 2000}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Cycles to Failure", "PS", None, None}, 
PlotLabel -> "Plot 2a\nNominal Probability of Survival", 
PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

[image]

```
n = 1000;  (* number of bootstrapped samples *)
bSamp = RandomChoice[
cycles, {n, 
Length[cycles]}]  (* bootstrapped samples, each sample is 4 \
values long *);
sampleddistributions = 
TruncatedDistribution[{0, Infinity}, 
 SmoothKernelDistribution[#]] & /@ bSamp;  
(* n fitted distributions *)
psvaluesTable = 
Table[SurvivalFunction[i, rng = Range[0., 2000]], {i, 
sampleddistributions}]  (* n PS lists, each PS list coresponds to \
cycles to failure values that range from 0 to 2,000 on a 1 cycle \
increment producing 2001 PS values in each list *);

psdata=Table[Null,{n}];
psplot=Table[Null,{n}];
cyclelist=Range[0.,2000];
i=0;
Do[{
i=i+1;
If[i>n,Break[]];
psdata[[i]]=Transpose[{cyclelist,psvaluesTable[[i]]}];
psplot[[i]]=ListPlot[psdata[[i]],Joined->True,PlotStyle->Green];},
{n}]
Dimensions[psplot]
psplot;
combinedPSlistplot=Show[psplot,FrameLabel->{"Cycles to Failure (cycles)","Probability    of Survival"},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"Cycles to Failure","PS",None,None},PlotLabel->"Plot    3\nCombined PS ListPlot"]
plotindex=Range[1,n];
psplotdata=Transpose[{plotindex,psplot}];
```

[image]

```
lower=Table[Quantile[i,.05],{i,Transpose[psvaluesTable]}]  (* Determines the lower 95%     single-sided confidence limit values *);lowerdata=Transpose[{rng,lower}];
plot4=ListLinePlot[lowerdata,PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{{Dashed,Blue}},Frame- >True,PlotLabel->"Plot 4\nLower 95% Single-Sided Confidence Level"]
lowerinterp=Interpolation[lower];
Show[combinedPSlistplot,plot4,plot2a,PlotLabel->"Final Plot"]
```

[image]

[image]

```
cyclesOfInterest = 500;
{lowerinterp[cyclesOfInterest], ps[cyclesOfInterest]}
```

{0.821289, 0.918629}

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your calculations but with so little data a better approach would be to fit a parametric distribution for time to failure that makes sense in the context of your problem.  The result you obtain is very much dependent on the form of the distribution you choose.  What do you expect the hazard rate to look like.

Comment: I agree, results are highly dependent on the form of the theoretical distribution chosen. Choosing an appropriate distribution for fitting is a strong function of whether there is symmetry expressed in the data. With so few observations I don't think it's possible to produce a histogram to determine this. This is what is appealing about the bootstrap. A general rule of thumb minimum is 20 non-duplicative points for an engineering-accuracy fit to a theoretical distribution. Not sure where this rule came from.

Comment: Are the processes anyhow censored on the left or on the right?

Comment: @rhermans. There is no censoring whatsoever in the 4 data values. All 4 are catastrophic fatigue failures. By chance are you able to confirm my results using another tool ? Thanks.